# Using a generic Component with resolveComponentFactory result in Component<{}> instead of <T>

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular-dynamic-components

I have build a dialog service which dynamically create a DialogComponent with a child component.

I want my DialogComponent to be a generic class of `<T>` since i wish to type for whatever component child i'm using. I'm currently create my DialogComponent using theses lines ->

```
const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(DialogComponent);
const componentRef = componentFactory.create(new DialogInjector(this.injector, map));
```

The problem is that the resolveComponentFactory is actually returning a `DialogComponent<{}>` instead of `T`. I did try to cast but it's seem i can't because some methods is missing.

I'm wondering how i could achieve such thing !

Thanks.

**EDIT**

`this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory<DialogComponent<T>>` did the tricks..

Comment: have you tried `.resolveComponentFactory<DialogComponent<T>>(DialogComponent);`?

Comment: It did works.. thanks

Comment: Can you propose it as an answer ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the right types, you need to pass the wanted type in the generic typing of `resolveComponentFactory`:

```
this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory<DialogComponent<T>>(DialogComponent);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're sure about yourself, just bypass the type checking with a function.

```js
myFunction<T>(className: T): { componentFactory: T, componentRef: any } {
  const componentFactory: T = this
    .componentFactoryResolver
    .resolveComponentFactory(className) as any;
  const componentRef = componentFactory
    .create(new DialogInjector(this.injector, map));
  return { componentFactory, componentRef };
}

const { componentFactory, componentRef } = myFunction(DialogComponent);
```

This might be an issue in the type definition of the framework. This code is a workaround, use it if you don't find anything else.